# Where can I find conduit bends less than 90degrees?

Tags: conduit

I'm about to run some conduit underground, and due to various obstacles can't do a dead-straight run.  I certainly don't want to add 90degree turns due to the extra drag when pulling a cable though.  But in all my searches 90degree bends are the only ones that anyone seems to sell.  Where can I find 45/30/20/10 degree bends?

Thanks!

Comment: What type and size of conduit? With pvc I use heat blankets to make minor bends, with metal I just bend it by hand on smaller sizes (under 1”) and a hydraulic bender for larger sizes.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to try the hairdryer plus spring (to avoid kinking).

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a 135 degree elbow.

Comment: And THAT'S the answer I was looking for, thank you @AndrewMorton.  Never occurred to me that I was looking for the inverse of what I wanted, doh!

Comment: I don't think you want a 135. That's beyond 90. The nominal description refers to the angle _from straight_.

Comment: @isherwood Perhaps the terminology differs between the U.K. and the U.S.A. A 180 degree angle is a flat angle (think of triangles).

Comment: The tools for bending metal conduits in the US mark the degrees of deflection from flat. This makes easy math for adding up to the maximum 360 degrees between boxes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, so the shallowest bends (what I would call a 22-1/2 degree bend, for example) are 157-1/2 degree elbows in U.K.? That would surprise me.

Comment: @isherwood England is apparently not big enough for 22.5 degree bends to fit. [Elsewhere](https://www.plasticpipeshop.co.uk/Metric-Plain-PVC-Fittings_c_592.html), in fact almost everywhere else, I did find 45 degree elbows which are the expected angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a shopping question and might get shut but you can buy conduit bends at any electrical supply house.

In my opinion, two 45s are only slightly less drag than a single 90, but the large radius 90s (aka "sweeps") are better than two 45's.  Oversizing the conduit helps all around.

Answer (score 3):

You can also bend your conduit to spec.  With metal conduit up to about 3/4" or 1",  you use a tubing bender sized for the pipe.  For bigger metal conduit you use a brake like a Hossfeld Bender.

With PVC conduit, you heat it up in a particular way.